# How do you get input until a newline in C++?

Tags: c++, scanf, cin

I'm reading input using `cin`. If I leave the input blank (and just hit enter), the cursor moves to a new line and asks for input again. Is there any way to make `cin` or `scanf` just return an empty string in this case?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `operator>>`, use [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/getline).

```
std::string data;
std::getline(std::cin, data);
```

Side note: There's no recursion involved here.  Recursion is when a function calls itself, that's not happening here.

Comment: well that's what I meant(by meant I mean how Jesse edited it, not function recursion. sorry for being new to this, I guess I can't really describe issues at my level yet.

Comment: @user: No worries, I wasn't berating you for using incorrect terminology, I was simply correcting your terminology, for your own benefit.